# GHC splitAt performance

Tags: haskell, ghc

splitAt is implemented in GHC in this way:

```
splitAt n xs  =  (take n xs, drop n xs)
```

1. So does, splitAt do double the work or is there some behind the curtain optimization?
2. Furthermore, take and drop generate a recursive process. Why is that. After all they are library functions and beauty is not as important. Why aren't they implemented to create an iterative process?

Comment: This is not how `splitAt` is defined in GHC. Look again.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#splitAt

Comment: (2) "Recursion" is a inductive definition of the solution; a method of building solution to one problem using a solution to another problem. It is not clear what you mean by "iterative process", and why it is a concern.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The definition you are looking at is the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) Prelude definition.

Quoting from that page (emphasis mine)

> In this chapter the entire Haskell Prelude is given. It constitutes a specification for the Prelude. *Many of the definitions are written with clarity rather than efficiency in mind*, and it is not required that the specification be implemented as shown here.

So in the GHC source, when you see

```
#ifdef USE_REPORT_PRELUDE
    // Haskell report prelude definition here (inefficient)
#else
    // Efficient definition here
#endif
```

you should read the `#else` branch if you want to see the definition that will normally be used - unless you specifically ask for the Haskell Report definitions.

Comment: I'm not convinced the convoluted definition of `split` is any better than the naive one using `take` and `drop`.

Comment: @augustss agreed — at least it's not better in all cases. I'm considering writing a piece about this.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka Please do, that would be very illuminating, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, recursive process are usually what you want when you're dealing with lists, because they're a spine-lazy data structure. Consider the following the code:

`head (take 100 [1 ..])`

If we follow the code, we'll eventually arrive to the following expression: `1 : take (100 - 1) [2 ..]`. Since we're only interested in the head of the list, the recursive call to `take` is never evaluated. However if `take` were to be implemented as an iterative process, it would need to iterate through all 100 elements, even if only the first element is needed.